# Value Error: need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, windows, powershell, batch-file

I have looked at the suggested similar questions and whilst useful, do not actual match my problem and I'm still struggling.

I am using a batch file to run a series of python files, and one of these python scripts returns a variable to be used as an argument in a later script (it has to be exported to console because it is also used as a parameter in an executable.)

By batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
@title AutoStats
set raw_dir ='raw_directory'
set today_dir ='today_directory'
set archive_dir='archive_directory'
set error_file='error_directory'
set DateEstate='dE'
set OTQ_File='OTQ_File'


cd C:\dev\OTQtxt
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('get_date.py') do set $date=%%a

python create_csv.py %$date% %raw_dir% %archive_dir% %error_file%


pause
```

The python script looks like this:

```
from sys import argv

date, raw_dir, today_dir, archive_dir, error_file = argv[1:]

print date
print raw_dir
print today_dir
print archive_dir
print error_file
```

The reason for using `argv[1:]` is because I don't want to use the script name as an argument

In the future it will obviously do more than this, this is just for testing whether I can get the arguments in.

The error is as the title states. This only occurs when running it from the batch file, if I run it from powershell and type in the arguments myself then it works.

I find it odd that when typing the arguments myself in powershell the script works fine, when using the parameters set in the .bat it returns an error.

Can anybody shed some light on why this might be. I've never used batch files until now so it might just be a simple mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the problem pointed out by Ffisegydd was correct, the real mistake causing the problem to happen with a different number of argument was with with setting of parameters in the batch file.

for the first 2 `set` lines I added a space after the parameter name:

```
set today_dir ='today_directory'
```

should have been:

```
set today_dir='today_directory'
```